# Sending mail in lambda function using nodejs

Tags: node.js, lambda, nodemailer

I am trying to send mail using nodeJS via lambda function in AWS.
Below is the code i have written.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
   var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
       host: 'smtp.mydomain.com',
       port:25,
       secure : true
   });
var text = 'Email body goes here';
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'fromUserMail',
    to: 'toUserMail',
    subject: 'Test subject',
    text: text
};
const response = await new Promise((rsv, rjt) => {
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
        return rjt(error)
    } 
    rsv('Email sent'); 
  });
});

return {
    statusCode: 280,
    body: JSON.stringify({
       input: response
    })
   }
}
```

I have configured VPC in order to access smtp.
On running the code error i am getting

```
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Connection timeout",
  "trace": [
  "Error: Connection timeout",
  "    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/var/task/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp- 
    connection/index.js:774:19)",
  "    at SMTPConnection._onError (/var/task/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp- 
  connection/index.js:760:20)",
  "    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp- 
  connection/index.js:229:22)",
  "    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)",
  "    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)"
 ]
 }
```

But i have having timeout of 30 mins and this error is coming after 1 min of execution so thats not timeout problem i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You should clarify following things first.

1. Is it Ok to use your code to send an email running outside lambda function
2. Double check the SMTP server, SMTP port, SES ID and SES Password provided in the lambda function

I setup lambda function to send email using SMTP, no need to config its VPC

Comment: Smtp server is internal one, so i don't need to provide id or password. VPC is configured to use access internal server.